# Hole in ceiling

Tags: hole-repair

[image]Just saw this hole in ceiling, it was behind the light fixture so never noticed until now. What was the best way to fix it, fill the hole with some spackle? Not sure sure what it’s from, any reason for concern?

Comment: How large is the hole? For a small defect, spackle should work fine. For something larger, you may need some structural support.

Comment: It’s about an inch

Answer (score 2):

That looks like simple mechanical damage. Likely from the last time the light fixture was replaced. Standard drywall patching methods ("spackle") will work just fine. Since you didn't even notice it, I wouldn't worry about a perfect smooth job and painting it - just patch it and it will be hardly visible at all.

Answer (score 1):

The hole around the fixture was probably was probably patched before since you can see the change in the texture and then somehow nicked.  Get a small container of spackle and a small knife and have at it. You can improve the texture if you put a small amount of spackle on a tile sponge and dab it on the ceiling.